# Fail on invalid or missing POMs

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Can I configure Maven to fail on missing or invalid POMs in the dependencies?

Usually, these only cause a `[WARNING]` and often the build fails much later. This confuses our developers.

Comment: There is a `dependency:analyze-only` goal, but not sure that it will fit your needs : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/failing-the-build-on-dependency-analysis-warnings.html

Comment: @Arnaud Thank you, but I don't see the connection to invalid POMs yet.

Comment: This plugin can help you fail on specific cases. https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html Have you tried it

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni We are using the enforcer plugin for various things. Is there a rule that fails on invalid or missing POMs?

Comment: You can write your own custom rule: 
https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni We have already done that for checking different things. But I guess that the enforcer plugin is "too late" in the process. It runs after dependency resolution has happened so all the invalid POMs were already incorporated. Of course, I could reiterate over all found POMs and check whether they are valid, but this will take a lot of time, probably too long to check it in every build.

Answer (score 0):

according to Maven [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/failing-the-build-on-dependency-analysis-warnings.html) A project's dependencies can be analyzed as part of the build process by binding the ***dependency:analyze-only*** goal to the lifecycle. By default, the analysis will be performed during the ***verify*** lifecycle phase. The plugin can then be configured to fail the build if any dependency analysis warnings are encountered by setting the ***failOnWarning*** parameter. See the following POM configuration for an example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>analyze</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>analyze-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I guess that the goal will only analyse whether the dependencies are used and undeclared or unused and declared (like `dependency:analyze`). I doubt that the plugin will look at warnings for invalid or missing POMs.